# How to pass parameter in where clause?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is what i tried. But i am not getting any error as well as no output. what i did wrong. and why this query is not working.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT balance FROM PersonalLoan_tb WHERE emp_id = '@term' AND paid_or_unpaid = '@Paid' ORDER BY Id DESC";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", paid);
```

But when i try with query without parameter i am getting output.

Comment: I don't think you need the single quotes around your variable names

Comment: You do not need single quotes `'@Param'` around parameter names.

Comment: @Rick: "do not need" is the wrong term, it isn't a parameter but a string literal if you pass it with apostrophes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're correct - I guess "You shouldn't have single quotes..." is more accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need the single quotes in the query string:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT balance FROM PersonalLoan_tb WHERE emp_id = @term AND paid_or_unpaid = @Paid ORDER BY Id DESC";
```

That said, I caution you against using `AddWithValue()`.  This must infer the types being passed into the string -- and any time code is not explicit, there is a danger of misinterpretation.  [Here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), for instance, is  a blog post explaining why this isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `single Quotes`<kbd>'</kbd> in parameters of Query

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT balance FROM PersonalLoan_tb WHERE emp_id = @term AND paid_or_unpaid = @Paid ORDER BY Id DESC";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", paid);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment - single quotes should not be there - they change the parameter to a literal. So your query is looking for a balance where the emp_id is the string '@term' and is won't be using the parameter passed in. Try

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT balance FROM PersonalLoan_tb WHERE emp_id = @term AND paid_or_unpaid = @Paid ORDER BY Id DESC";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", paid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything specified between single quote ('), will be considered as a string. So write parameter name without quote (') and it will work.

```
"SELECT balance FROM PersonalLoan_tb WHERE emp_id = @term AND paid_or_unpaid = @Paid ORDER BY Id DESC"
```

rest of the code will be same.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT balance FROM PersonalLoan_tb WHERE emp_id = @term AND paid_or_unpaid = @Paid ORDER BY Id DESC";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", paid);
```